# Interaction between Graveyard Busybody and Over My Dead Bodies

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-joke-cards

If a player controls [Graveyard Busybody](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439423) and there is an [Over My Dead Bodies](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439452) in play, what happens due to a creature being in both player's graveyards. In particular, could a creature with vigilance attacking it's owner from it's owner's graveyard still be used by that owner to block, could it block itself?

> Graveyard Busybody: All graveyards are also your graveyards.
>
> Over My Dead Bodies: Creature cards in graveyards can attack and block as though they were on the battlefield

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from the [FAQ](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/unstable-faqawaslfaqpaftidawabiajtbt-2017-12-06):

> What does it mean that "all graveyards are also your graveyards"?
>
> It means each graveyard is no longer under the control of other players. They're your graveyards now, you control them.

Since you are the only controller of all graveyards, the owner does not get to use the creature to block.

Comment: I was confused by the word also, read it as yours as well as the original owner, not yours in addition to your own. We're talking an un set here too, so a creature being able to block itself wouldn't be that crazy, relatively speaking.